# Stick element to the keyboard bottom during animations

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard

I'm struggling with keyboard in iOS 8 trying to glue an element above it during animations. Like in Messages they have input pushing up by appearing keyboard. I've found lots of topics here, but all of them say how to handle appearing keyboard, but not dismissal. Seems Apple use some other curve or speed whatever by dismissal, so I have asynchronism when close the keyboard, while appearing animation is perfectly synchronised.

Here is what I've got by now:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHideOrShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHideOrShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

- (void)keyboardWillHideOrShow:(NSNotification *)note {
    NSDictionary *userInfo = note.userInfo;
    CGRect keyboardEndFrame = [userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    [self adjustFormContainerSize]; // Method opening orange card

    UIViewAnimationCurve curve = [userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] unsignedIntegerValue];
    UIViewAnimationOptions options = (curve << 16) | UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState;
    NSTimeInterval duration = [userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];

    self.buttonContainerBottom.constant = keyboardEndFrame.size.height;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration
                          delay:0.0
                        options:options
                     animations:^{
                         [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                     }
                     completion:nil];
}
```

And the result in simulator: http://monosnap.com/file/BwxJdthPGzCqJnxeQLEg5bb8smvxdb

What's wrong with backward animation, how to synchronise it?

Comment: Can you make your custom view an inputAccesoryView?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use

[DAkeyboard](https://github.com/danielamitay/DAKeyboardControl)

it's very good component for handle this problem